# Unable to make unique index in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

```
const popupSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        /**
         * @type schema field / ObjectId
         * @description User whose popus are stored.
         * @note should be required
         */

        user_id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User",
            required:true,
            index: { unique: true }
        },
        /**
         * @type schema field / Array
         * @description Information of all the popups of the User.
         */

        popupsArray: [popupDetails]
    },
    opts
);
```

This is my schema and I want to make user_id a unique_index. There is no other entry in the schema with the same user_id.
I am running this script to achieve the same:

```
await popups
    .createIndexes(
        {user_id:1}
    )
    .then(res => {
            console.log("done")
        }
    ).catch((err)=>{
        console.log("error in indexing popups",err)
    })
```

But this script is terminating with error =>
Index with name: user_id_1 already exists with different options.
{
ok: 0,
code: 85,
codeName: 'IndexOptionsConflict'
}

How can I make user_id unique_index? I also tried required:true in user_id but it won't work.

I have added `required:true` just before running this script. Will this make any difference?

Comment: I suspect index is already created. What doe this do in mongo shell `db.popup.getIndexes()`

Comment: I checked compass it is only _id is unique!

Comment: That does not guarantee that an index does not exist already for user_id. Check if you can actually find out if index exists, that is what the error is about.

Comment: Anyway, what I would change about your code if i wrote it would be : `let result = await popups
    .createIndex(
        {user_id: 1},{unique: true}
    ); console.log(result); `

Comment: With await you do not need a then. Also you can use createIndex here instead of createIndexes.

Comment: See if the mongoose syncIndexes function works for this.

Comment: If each popup document will have a unique `user_id` there is no point to separating the popup schema from user schema.

Comment: @TusharShahi No it won't work